# background style on absolute positioned element within a relative one

Tags: html, css

having a general css issue while creating a page with animations. I have a main container that's positioned relative and more than one container that's absolute positioned within that for the purpose of changing the background styles like color of the whole page and shifting it around to reveal the other containers of different colors under it via z-index.

why doesn't the background color show up?

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 50%;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg green">green</div>
  <div class="bg blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you position something as `absolute`, it is removed from the document flow. This means that now `main` has nothing to give it any height (since the default is `auto`), and so therefore the children's `height: 100%` is still `0`. The text is still visible because the default of `overflow-y` is `visible`.

To fix it, give `main` some height.

```css
body, html, .main { height: 100% }
.main {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 50%;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg green">green</div>
  <div class="bg blue">blue</div>
</div>
```